# Setting up the cmake and package.xml of navigation stack

Tags: cmake, navigation, ros, robotics

I´m currently finishing my degree thesis which consists on developing an autonomous robot as cheap as possible. For this, I have been using a camera, a couple of motor drivers (Roboclaw 2x15A), a camera, 4 motors, aruco nodes for localization and 2 RPis (3B+ and 4). Right, everything works OK: camera topics publish info gathered from the aruco tag detection, etc.

The main problem is that I have my navigation package from [navigation stack ros](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) already created but I can´t come up with the dependencies of the package. So I would like to know which dependencies should have the CMake file and the package.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I have just created another package with the dependencies I thought that were necessary and then copy the CMake changing the project name.
For the package.xml, just add:

```
<build_depend>your_dependency</build_depend>
<exec_depend>your_dependency</exec_depend>
```

As many times as dependencies you want to add.